# linux file permission and different user privilege

Tags: linux

**root user creates one file which has 664 permission.**

```
[root]# ls -trl
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  9 08:40 mnode-log-ipc-shm_5500
```

**I am going to use the admin level to open the file with opening mode WRITE/READ , here is my test code.**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{       
    char filename[] = "./mnode-log-ipc-shm_5500";

    if ( argc < 2 ) 
    {   
        printf("./mytest id\n");
        return 0;
    }   
    int gid = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d gid\n", gid);
    if ( -1 == setgid(gid))
        printf("set gid to error:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    if ( -1 == setuid(gid))
        printf("set uid to error:%s\n", strerror(errno));
    int fds = open(filename, O_RDWR);  
    if(fds < 0)  
    {   
        printf("failed with uid:%d gid:%d\n", getuid(), getgid());  
        fprintf(stderr, "open error %s\n", strerror(errno));  
    }   
    else
    {   
        printf("sucess with uid:%d gid:%d\n", getuid(), getgid());  
        close(fds);
    }   

    while (1) 
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

**my expectation is open API will return error, because the file for other user permission just is readable, but the real result is admin user can open it. I am confusing about this, could someone explain to me why?**

```
[root@0-3 ~]# ./mytest 501    
501 gid
```

sucess with uid:501 gid:501

```
[root@0-3 ~]# ps -ef | grep mytest    
admin     1337 13006  0 05:04 pts/1    00:00:00 ./mytest 501    
root      1454  1344  0 05:04 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mytest
```

Comment: Question about Un*x/Linux filesystems, basic right and standard base, could better be asked to https://unix.stackexchange.com/!

Answer (score 1):

You need to [understand linux file permission](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions).

For file mnode-log-ipc-shm_5500, it has read, write permission to user `root` and group `root`, and only have read permission to `others`. Therefore, admin does not have enough permission to write content to the file.

There are many approaches to enable write access:

1. Gain higher permission (write permission) to other users, execute this command `chmod o+w mnode-log-ipc-shm_5500`
2. Change the owner to admin, execute this command `chown admin mnode-log-ipc-shm_5500`
3. Use [access control list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list), which is more advance approach in this case

See more: [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)

Comment: Thanks Ben.My question is this function "int fds = open(filename, O_RDWR);"  should be failed, because at this time, admin user calls this function, and admin user just have permission to read, however, the return value of this API is success. this makes me confusion.

Comment: You only initialise the file descriptor for the file, underlying you haven't done any write access to the file. If you call `write` the return value is 0 because none of the bytes can write to the file due to not enough permission.

Comment: hi, Ben, but I use others user level to call this API, some of  them are failed, some of them are successful.

Comment: let me show you. this is output of command "passwd" 
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin


tcpdump:x:72:72::/:/sbin/nologin


admin:x:1499:1499::/home/admin:/bin/bash

this is my test application executive result.

[root@0-19 ~]# ./mytest 1499

1499 gid

sucess with uid:1499 gid:1499

[root@0-19 ~]# ./mytest 72

72 gid

failed with uid:72 gid:72

open error Permission denied

you can see for user 1499(admin), the API return value is 0(success), for user 72(tcpdump), the API return value is -1(failure)

Comment: how about the permission of file parent folder? can you check the groups of admin / tcpdump and have execute permission for them?

Comment: hi, Ben, the file is under two layer folder, /run/mavenir/mnode-log-ipc-shm_5500.
for run folder, it is drwxr-xr-x   28 root root 1040 Dec 12 19:18 run.
for mavenir folder, it is drwxr-x---  2 admin   admin    380 Dec 12 19:18 mavenir.
for you question "can you check the groups of admin / tcpdump and have execute permission for them?" 
I don't know how to check it, would you share some commands with me?

Comment: `groups {user}` command can check which groups {user} belongs to, you should check with `groups admin`. The folder mavenir don't have rwx permission for others that's why others user cannot open the file. related link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work

Comment: hi, Ben,  since the file's  parent directory user is admin, even though the file was created by root user. admin user still can open it with read/write mode, right?

Comment: linux file permission is sophisticated, recommend you to read tutorial to understand the fundamental knowledge. Even though, for you information given, the folder `mavenir` permission is `drwxr-x--- admin admin`, you don't have write access to file mnode-log-ipc-shm_5500 because `-rw-rw-r-- root root`.

Comment: ok. thanks a lot for your patient explanation about this issue.